# App crashes on parse push notification when the app is not running

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

When I open my android app and test parse push notification, it works. But when I killed my app from multitasking and test again, app crashes.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Parse.initialize(MainActivity.this, "cMm2mJvkRlIButQ0wM4lfj5veFxrQYUKw8P4mdM4", "bOplHPHvWb9IRzv2EbQnylWFgyveTsDYEspV2qs0");
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

**Error Log**

> 08-18 21:16:21.694  24406-24406/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.myatminsoe.mkeyboard, PID: 24406
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.parse.PushService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context
>   com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.applicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2771)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context
>   com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.applicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference
>               at com.parse.PushService.onCreate(PushService.java:238)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2761)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Can you give us some code ?

Comment: yes, added some code

Comment: The initialize of Parse should be done in Application and not in Activity

Comment: @cYrixmorten Thanks, that helped me.

Comment: No problem :) happy coding

Comment: @cYrixmorten can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @AmirFazwan you can download the blank project from https://parse.com/docs/downloads and see how it should be initialized there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the parse initialisation in Application onCreate and make sure you are calling it in the mainThread.

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).applicationId(
                    ...).build());
```

Comment: Don't know why you don't have any up votes. Worked great for me.